# Get sums by grouping a collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dictionary, meteor

I have a collection with fields: `number`, `a`, `b`, `c`.

I want to divide the collection in three based on the number and get separate sums of `a`, `b`, and `c` for each group division.

I have done this with

```
function sumList(amountList) {
  return _.reduce(amountList, function(sum, amount) {
    return sum + amount;
  }, -1);
}

// cursors
var group1 = Groups.find({ number: { $lte: 32 } }).fetch();
var group2 = Groups.find({ number: { $gte: 33, $lte: 70 } }).fetch();
var group3 = Groups.find({ number: { $gte: 71 } }).fetch();

// sums for group1
var group1SumA = sumList(_.pluck(group1, "a"));
var group1SumB = sumList(_.pluck(group1, "b"));
var group1SumC = sumList(_.pluck(group1, "c"));

// sums for group2
var group2SumA = sumList(_.pluck(group2, "a"));
var group2SumB = sumList(_.pluck(group2, "b"));
var group2SumC = sumList(_.pluck(group2, "c"));

// sums for group3
var group3SumA = sumList(_.pluck(group3 "a"));
var group3SumB = sumList(_.pluck(group3, "b"));
var group3SumC = sumList(_.pluck(group3, "c"));
```

It works but I think the code is very ugly.

I wonder if this can be done with some smart mapping. Besides, I guess it might have bad performance.

How can these sums be optimized?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** which will have the **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline operator to filter the collection on the `number` field.  The **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step then groups all the filtered input documents and applies the accumulator expression **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** to each field to get the sums.

Your pipeline would look like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "number": { "$lte": 32 } } /* group1 filter */
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "sumA": { "$sum": "$a" },
            "sumB": { "$sum": "$b" },
            "sumC": { "$sum": "$c" }
        }
    }
];
```

You can add the **[meteorhacks:aggregate package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** to implement the aggregation in Meteor:

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Since this package exposes **`.aggregate`** method on Mongo.Collection instances, you can then call the method to get the resulting array with the document that has the sums. For example

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var Coll = new Mongo.Collection('collectionName');
    Meteor.methods({
        sumList: function (filter) {
            var pipeline = [
                {
                    "$match": filter
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": 0,
                        "sumA": { "$sum": "$a" },
                        "sumB": { "$sum": "$b" },
                        "sumC": { "$sum": "$c" }
                    }
                }
            ];          
            var result = Coll.aggregate(pipeline);
            return result[0];
        }
    }); 
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // filters
    var group1 = { "number": { "$lte": 32 } };
    var group2 = { "number": { "$gte": 33, "$lte": 70 } };
    var group3 = { "number": { "$gte": 71 } };

    Meteor.call('sumList', group1, callback);
    //Meteor.call('sumList', group2, callback);
    //Meteor.call('sumList', group3, callback);

    function callback(err, result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried implementing it but I get the error `Exception while invoking method 'sumList' TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fetch'`. I thought `BudgetGroups.aggregate(pipeline)` would always return a cursor and not a object as the error msg indicates

Comment: @Jamgreen Actually there is no need to call the `fetch()` method as the aggregate method itself returns the result array. You can check the tests for it [**here**](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/blob/master/test.js).

Comment: It works when I remove `fetch()`. If I use console.log(result) in the method, I get the expected result but when I try using the value returned from `Meteor.call('sumList', group1, callback)`. I just get `undefined`. I have also tried `Meteor.call('sumList', group1, function(err, result) { return result });`